# I seem to have a error running this part of my game. Except it's a logic error and wont show up in the Compiler

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

**This part of the coding is for a turret in a tower defense game. As of right now it does not show up, if anyone sees a error help would be much appreciated.**

```
    package 
    {
        import flash.display.MovieClip;
        import flash.events.*;
        public class Turret extends MovieClip
        {
            private var _root:MovieClip;

            public function Turret()
            {
                this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED, beginClass);
                this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrameEvents);
            }
            private function beginClass(e:Event):void
**//Where I make the turret itself**            
{
                _root = MovieClip(root);
                this.graphics.beginFill(0xFFD700);
                this.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,12.5);
                this.graphics.endFill();
                this.graphics.beginFill(0xFFD700);
                this.graphics.drawRect(-2.5, 0, 5, 20);
                this.graphics.endFill();
            }
            private function eFrameEvents(e:Event):void
            {

                if (_root.gameOver)
                {
                    this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrameEvents);
                    MovieClip(this.parent).removeChild(this);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try getting rid of the beginClass function and add the drawing calls to the constructor. Also make sure the Turrent is aaded to the scene and try commenting out the if statement to make sure it's not removing the movie clip.

Comment: What kind of error was that ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error where you have placed your comment before the function. Remove the asterixs before it...

```
...
private function beginClass(e:Event):void
//Where I make the turret itself            
{
    _root = MovieClip(root);
    ...
```